# What is statistical way of determining that questions are chosen at random from a test bank?

Tags: random-variable, combinatorics

I'm using a website for a professional certification that provides practice tests with questions generated from a question bank. The site claims that questions are chosen at random from a question bank of 390 questions. Each exam has 65 questions. However, when I retake the test, I feel like there are way too many repeated questions for them to be chosen truly chosen at random.

I'm not sure how to structure a question around the gut feeling.  I think it might be a confidence interval question like  "If _____% of questions are the same questions from a previous test, what is the probability that the test questions are chosen at random"?

Would it be something like

$$ {{390}\choose{65}} \cdot p^{n-k} 1-p^{k}$$   ?

Comment: This is a classic [capture-recapture problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=capture%20recapture).  The *hypergeometric* distribution is the relevant one rather than the binomial probability shown in the question.